# Can import pytorch but not torch

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, torch

I installed torch using `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`.
I can `import pytorch` but not `import torch`. I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-eb42ca6e4af3>", line 1, in <module>
    import torch

  File "C:\Users\anirb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)

  File "C:\Users\anirb\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

Comment: [pytorch](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch/) =/= [torch](https://pypi.org/project/torch/) ([GitHub: pytorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your 'pytorch' which you have installed and try running this using 'conda' line:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c soumith
```

If it didn't work, try to run the following code in cmd

```
pip install torchvision
```

Comment: I just tried it, I still can't `import torch` but can `import pytorch`

Comment: Ok, let's try this ```conda install pytorch torchvision -c soumith``` dont install the CUDA version if you dont have Nvidia GPU on your machine that supports.

Comment: Yes `conda install pytorch torchvision -c soumith` works perfectly. I can now import torch. If you edit your answer I can accept the same, thanks! As a quick follow up question, I have an import error for IterableDataset from torch module. Is there any fix?

Comment: How are you importing it? Can you show me the error? And what's your pytorch version? Let's try this: ```from torch.utils.data import IterableDataset```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-34a28a3f1c60>", line 1, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data import IterableDataset

ImportError: cannot import name 'IterableDataset' from 'torch.utils.data' (C:\Users\anirb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\__init__.py)

Comment: [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.IterableDataset) Which pytorch version are you using? I am using 1.3 and it seems to be correctly imported.

Comment: Can you upgrade your pytorch version? IterableDataset class was introduced in pytorch 1.2, so it won't work in lower versions.

Comment: I am facing issues with installing pytorch using the command given on their site. `import torch` doesn't work with any of the commands there.

Answer (score 0):

install `torchvision` using `pip install torchvision` it should work fine

Comment: I just tried it, I still can't `import torch` but can `import pytorch`

Comment: are you using jupyter notebook? have you checked whether you are using the same env in which you have installed the `torchvision`?

Comment: I have not created virtual environments, so that is not an issue. And no I am using Spyder IDE.